# How do I configure a home.parity address for my parity node browser?

Tags: browsers, parity, configuration

How can I configure my linux system to point any `.parity` address to my parity web application running on localhost port 8080?

[image: parity browser screenshot]

> For the best experience it is recommended to use subdomains-based routing.
>
> Instead of: http://localhost:8080/home/
>   in your address bar you would see: http://home.parity/
>
> To configure the routing add the following link to your proxy configuration URL:
>
> http://localhost:8080/proxy/proxy.pac

Which contains:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.parity"))
    {
        return "PROXY localhost:8080";
    }

    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parity is using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config (the file you pasted).

You have two options:

1. Configure your *system* to use that proxy auto-configuration file (you will be able to use `home.parity` on all browsers, there are tutorial links provided when you click yellow warning sign.
2. Configure your *browser* to use the proxy. For Chrome you can just install [Parity Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/parity-ethereum-integrati/fgodinogimdopkigkcoelpfkbnpngalc) (or any other proxy extension) . For Firefox you can use FoxyProxy for instance.